# How to: Run Django Project in Subpath

Tags: python, django

Okay, so I'd like to start by saying that I am not running NGINX like many of the other questions I've seen.I'm running Gunicorn alongside Whitenoise.  My task is to implement scientific plots in a separate directory of an existing website. My problem is getting the django project to not run in the root directory of the website. I need it to run in a directory like 'example.com/app',so that I can call the plotting application from there as opposed to the main webpage.

I tried changing the application urls.py to say 'example.com/app/pretty_plots' and navigating to the page that way, but it fails to load all of the resources. Everything works as expected if I change the web access path of the app to '/' (eliminating the original homepage), and navigating to example.com/pretty_plots, but I'd like to leave the home page intact. FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/app' did not do the trick for me either.

URLConf
mysite/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import plots.plotly_apps


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('plots/',  include('plots.urls')),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
]
```

The above code works from the root, but not anywhere else. I see no options of configuring Whitenoise to run Django from a subpath. The example.com/app/pretty_plots page does not run all of the resources needed to render the plots. Any help would be greatly appreciate!